# App generated requests issue

Tags: facebook, request, facebook-c#-sdk

I am having an issue using app generated requests using the facebook c sharp ssk; here is my code.

```
`FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(FacebookApplication.Current.AppId, FacebookApplication.Current.AppSecret);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "Test: Action is required";
parameters.data = "Custom Data Here";
dynamic result = app.Post(String.Format("{0}/apprequests", member.FacebookId), parameters);`
```

the result actually has the request id, but the notification never shows on the member page.
I am working on localhost could this be the problem

Answer (score 2):

App generated requests do not show notifications as of the new SDK, i was puzzled by the same thing. These requests only increment the bookmark counter or show a little red request count on the new recommendations panel